# Imprimir lista encadeada em C

Tags: c, lista, array

Estou criando um programa que recebe um vetor e cria uma lista encadeada. Preciso de ajuda para criar a função "imprimir()", que imprime a lista encadeada gerada. Não sei como proceder.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>

// elemento da lista
typedef struct estr {

        int valor;

        struct estr *prox;

} NO;

NO* insereNoNaLista(NO* p, NO* lista){
    if(!lista) return p; //Se não houver nada na caixa de nós(lista = NULL), o ponteiro p aponta para NULL
    while(lista->prox != NULL ){ //"lista->prox = NULL" eh o ultimo elemento da lista
        lista = lista->prox; //Percorre os nós até que próximo elemento seja NULL
    }
    lista->prox = p; //Se lista->prox não for NULL, então o ponteiro p guarda o endereço de memoria do proximo elemento
    return lista; //devolve lista com todos os nos
}

//Recebe um vetor de inteiros e devolve uma lista ligada de nos
NO* deVetorParaLista(int *v, int t){
    int i;
    NO* p = NULL; 
    NO* lista = NULL; 

    for(i = 0; i < t; i++ ){
        p = malloc(sizeof(NO)); 
        p->valor = v[i]; 
        p->prox = NULL;
        lista = insereNoNaLista(p, lista); 
    }
    return lista;
}

void imprimir()

int main() {

    int v[] = {1,53,43,68,99, -7};
    int t = (sizeof(v))/sizeof(int); //tamanho do vetor v
    deVetorParaLista(v, t);

}
```

Outra dúvida: as funções *insereNoNaLista* e *deVetorParaLista* retornam "lista". De qual forma eu poderia mesclar essas duas funções em uma única ou utilizar melhores práticas de programação?

Comment: Tem que ir passando pelo prox e imprimindo ''printf'' os valores que desejar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Uma boa prática de programação seria usar nomes mais explicativos para as variáveis. Num programa pequeno como esse não tem problema, mas em programas mais complexos é melhor usar nomes que rotulem minimamente o propósito da variável, especialmente se ela for algo mais que um simples contador.

Outra é sempre liberar memória quando alocar dinamicamente. Em geral para cada malloc deve haver um free. Novamente não seria um problema num programa pequeno e sem alocação repetitiva a critério do usuário, e que nem usa muita memória como é o seu caso pois o kernel libera a memória assim que o processo é encerrado. Mas é sempre uma boa prática :) .

Eu tomei a liberdade de seguir suas sugestões e fazer uma versão mesclada das duas primeiras funções e adicionar uma função para limpeza de memória.

Boa sorte nos estudos.

```
// elemento da lista
typedef struct estr 
{

    int valor;
    struct estr *prox;

} NO;
//Recebe um vetor de inteiros e devolve uma lista ligada de nos
NO* deVetorParaLista(int *v, int t)
{
    int i;
    NO* p = NULL;
    NO* a = NULL;//endereco do no anterior
    NO* lista = NULL;

    for(i = 0; i < t; i++ )
    {
        p = (NO*)malloc(sizeof(NO));
        p->valor = v[i];
        p->prox = NULL;

        if(i==0)
        {
            //copia primeiro endereco para variavel a ser retornada
            lista=p;
        }else{
            //se nao for o primeiro elemento copia endereco para 'prox' do no anterior
            a->prox=p;
        }
        a=p;
    }
    return lista;
}

void imprimir(NO *p)
{
    printf("\n");
    while(p!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%d",p->valor);
        printf("\n");
        p=p->prox;
    }
}
//libera memoria alocada
void limparLista(NO *p)
{
    NO *n;
    while(p!=NULL)
    {
        n=p->prox;
        free(p);
        p=n;
    }
}

int main()
{

    int v[] = {5,17,-2,55,1000};
    int t = (sizeof(v))/sizeof(int); //tamanho do vetor v
    NO* p=deVetorParaLista(v, t);

    imprimir(p);

    //limpar lista(somente depois de usa-la)
    limparLista(p);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, Tsui! Você pode me explicar a diferença(conceito) entre o ponteiro p e a lista? e por que não podemos escrever "void imprimir(NO *lista)". Pelo que eu entendi, o ponteiro aponta para um local de memória, enquanto a lista funciona como uma "caixa" de nós

Comment: A variável 'NO* lista' é local da função 'deVetorParaLista(int*,int)'. Há duas variáveis 'NO* p' nesse código, talvez isso tenha te confundido, uma da função 'limparLista(NO*)' que recebe o argumento e outra em 'main()'. Não podemos escrever  "void imprimir(NO *lista)" só porque não há nenhuma variável com esse nome no escopo de 'main()'. Todas essas variáveis recebem nada mais que o endereço do primeiro elemento da lista através do qual ela é acessada.